# download spring with dependencies

Tags: java, spring, jar, download, dependencies

is there a way to get a spring-with-dependencies.zip for the latest version of spring (3.0x) ?

I know that one could get whatever dependencies using maven/ivy but if I were NOT to use either of these tools, AND also without knowing which library versions are compatible, how can I get all the JARs one-shot ?

Just like CentOS re-assembles Redhat Enterprise for free, does anyone assemble spring for developers to use like earlier days ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `-with-dependencies.zip` distribution for versions up to 3.0.2, but not for 3.0.3, for some reason.

This package was discussed in [SPR-6575](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6575), but they seem to have lapsed again.

Answer (score 1):

Maven does this, although that's using a big tool - with other repercussions - for a somewhat smaller job.